# Windows 7 iso bootable usb - will it install ok on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: windows-7

Is there anything I need to do to ensure windows installs correctly on my laptop? 
Is it possible to set up dual OS with Windows 7/Ubuntu? If so, how?

The PC I'm using came with Windows 10 pre-installed
I have a bootable usb with Windows 7 that I would like to put on the laptop

I'm using ubuntu 17.04

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I need to do to ensure windows installs correctly on
>   my laptop?

No, just make sure that you install all of the drivers for the hardware afterwards.

> Is it possible to set up dual OS with Windows 7/Ubuntu?

Yes. In this case you will need to install Windows first and then Ubuntu second, and choose <kbd>Install alongside Windows 7</kbd> in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

I find it is easier to *first* install Windows (7 or 10) and *then* to install a Linux distro for dual boot. Often the Windows installation process trashes grub, but I've not had Ubuntu installation impact Windows. If Windows *does* mess with grub, try [Grub Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows). Back up the entire disk, though, as it has been claimed that Windows installation can destroy partitions.

In any case, the installation of Windows from USB is controlled by BIOS/UEFI boot setup. If the media is designed for UEFI, you can leave Secure Boot and UEFI on; otherwise, you'll have to change these settings to match your media.

BTW, since MS dropped support for Windows 7, you'd be better off dual-booting Windows 10.

Comment: I do have my windows 10 product key, I might go that route. Should I install windows (removing linux) and then reinstall linux doing a dual boot?

Comment: That would be my own choice, since Windows installation takes hours to complete, but Ubuntu is just a matter of minutes. You may not need to remove Linux, but there's a chance Windows will mess up that partition. Just repartition as needed after Windows for Ubuntu space.